# text is displaying below Add to cart button

Tags: html, css

please visit : [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-chutki-keychain.html) search for "Selling Price" using Ctrl + F.

you can see this text "**Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery**" is displaying above "Add to cart" button. but in this [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html) , **its displaying below add to cart button**. please help me to display "Selling Price + Rs 10 Delivery" text above "Add to cart" button....

we are using  following code :

```
.product-view .product-essential .product-shop {

text-align : left;
position:relative;
padding-bottom:0px;

}
```

**phtml**

```
<?php
echo " Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") .  " Delivery ";

    ?>
    <!-- shipping charges on product view pageee  -->

    <!-- 3 sshippng -->

    <?php $deliveryPrice = $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") ?>
    <?php if($deliveryPrice === "0"): ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?> </p>
    <?php elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)): ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery "; ?> </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
        <?php echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") . " Delivery "; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in paragraph class sell_price you can add this style

```
.sell_price{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -44%;
}
```

[image: O/P image]

> try this

```
 <?php 
     $style='style="position:relative;margin-top:-44%;"';
     ?>
     <?php $deliveryPrice = $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") ?>
        <?php if($deliveryPrice === "0"): ?>
            <p class="sell_price" <?=$style?>><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?> </p>
        <?php elseif(empty($deliveryPrice)): ?>
            <p class="sell_price" <?=$style?>><?php echo "Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery "; ?> </p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="sell_price" <?=$style?>><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
            <?php echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") . " Delivery "; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i used your code, than it will work for link2 , but it will not work for link1

Comment: where are you using this code external css or internal

Comment: use internal and add ! important

Comment: i am using internal css, but still same problem is there. i am using this code : http://pastebin.com/m8XxmhFX

Comment: <p class="sell_price" style="position: relative;margin-top: -44%;"><?php echo "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"; ?> </p>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103591/discussion-between-sharma-vikram-and-baby-in-coding).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your html code. In link 1 you place your paragraph tag after the div class="widget" but in link 2 its not there. so place your paragraph tag after that div.

Comment: you can check through inspect element in your browser. inspect the p element in both link. you can see your p tag not in same position.

Comment: please give me complete code for using in internal css with important.

Answer (score 1):

There is your p tag is after the `product-options-bottom` div.

```
<div class="product-options-bottom">
<p class="sell_price">Selling Price + Rs 10 Delivery </p>
```

Put `p` to before `div` tag same way in your first link `p` tag is before `.add-to-box` div

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to end the `<p>` tag on your else statement

```
 <?php else: ?>
        <p class="sell_price"><?php echo "Selling Price"; ?>
        <?php echo "+ Rs " . $_product->getData("mp_local_shipping_charge") . " Delivery "; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```